# Using MongoDB data inside Hadoop with the help of Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, mongodb-java, mongodb-hadoop

I've been playing with the MongoInputFormat that allows having all documents in a MongoDB collection put through a MapReduce job written in Hadoop.

As you can see in the provided examples ([this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/examples/wordcount_split_test/src/main/java/com/mongodb/hadoop/examples/wordcount/split/WordCountSplitTest.java), [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/examples/wordcount/src/main/java/com/mongodb/hadoop/examples/wordcount/WordCount.java) and [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/examples/wordcount/src/main/java/com/mongodb/hadoop/examples/wordcount/WordCountXMLConfig.java)) the type the document is in that is provided to the mapper is a [BSONObject](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/org/bson/BSONObject.java) (an Interface in Java).

Now I also like [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/) very much which allows mapping the raw data from MongoDB into POJOs that are much easier to use.

Since I can only get a BSONObject as input I thought about using the method described at the bottom of [this page](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/MappingObjects) of the Morphia wiki:

```
BlogEntry blogEntry = morphia.fromDBObject(BlogEntry.class, blogEntryDbObj);
```

My problem is that this method requires a [DBObject](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/com/mongodb/DBObject.java) instead of a [BSONObject](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/org/bson/BSONObject.java).
A DBObject is really:

```
public interface DBObject extends BSONObject
```

So as you can see I cannot simply cast from BSONObject to DBObject and call the provided method.

How do I handle this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice that the `BSONObject` and `DBObject` interfaces are very similar. Just because a converson doesn't exist doesn't mean it's not easy to create a trivial one:

```
class BSONDBObject extends BasicBSONObject implements DBObject {
    boolean ispartial = false;
    public BSONDBObject(BSONObject source) {
        this.putAll(source);
    }
    public boolean isPartialObject() {
        return ispartial;
    }
    public void markAsPartialObject() {
        this.ispartial = true;
    }
}
```

Now, you just need to

```
BSONObject bson; // Filled by the MongoInputFormat
BSONBDObject dbo = BSONDBObject(bson);
EntityCache = entityCache = new DefaultEntityCache();
BlogEntry blogEntry = morphia().fromDBObject(BlogEntry.class, dbo, entityCache);
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution that works for me:

- First make it into a JSON text string
- Parse this into a DBObject
- Map that using Morphia to a useful instance.

Effectively I now have something like this:

```
BSONObject bson; // Filled by the MongoInputFormat

EntityCache = entityCache = new DefaultEntityCache();
String json = JSON.serialize(bson)    
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(json);
BlogEntry blogEntry = morphia().fromDBObject(BlogEntry.class, dbObject, entityCache);
```

Comment: -1: This is not the way to do this. There is no need to serialize and unserialize your data just to perform such a trivial conversion

Comment: Your answer is better, but it is also more than a year AFTER the point in time when I needed it. I think this downvote is not very nice of you.

Comment: The reason that questions persist is so that they can be helpful to *others*. This is a really bad way of doing this, and I want to indicate that to future viewers. I only found this question because I needed the answer for something I'm working on now.